# server/client chat socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, chat

I have a server/client socket connection, each side can send a message to the other. The client who must begin the chat. I want to close the connection when one of the both sides (server and client) sends "quit" message.
here is my code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
class TCPClient { 

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
    { 
        String sentence; 
        String modifiedSentence; 
while(true){
        BufferedReader inFromUser = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789); 

        DataOutputStream outToServer = 
          new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


        BufferedReader inFromServer =
          new BufferedReader(new
          InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();

        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);

        if(modifiedSentence.equals("quit\n")) clientSocket.close();

}
    }
}


import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

class TCPServer { 

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
    { 
      String clientSentence; 
      String sentence; 

    BufferedReader inFromUser = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789); 

      while(true) { 

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept(); 

           BufferedReader inFromClient = 
              new BufferedReader(new
              InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));




           DataOutputStream outToClient =
             new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

           clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
System.out.println("FROM CLIENT: " + clientSentence);

           //capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
           sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
           outToClient.writeBytes(sentence);
       }
   }
}
```

Any help? :)

Comment: Don't confuse text and binary. If you want to use text don't use DataOutputStream or DataInputStream

Comment: The readline will remove \n so there is no point checking for it in the string, it can't be there.

Comment: You must also check the result of readLine() for null, and close the socket if so. I don't see a real question here.

Answer (score 1):

You have already written one line. Write another for "quit" and check this string when reading and close().

if you don't understand what you program is doing, use your debugger, that is what it is for.

Comment: Or don't write it that way in the first place. I was going to put a smiley but this is actually no joke.

Comment: Agreed. You could just close() when you want to close the connection.